# C# how to group List by objects with the same property values

Tags: c#, linq

assume I have the following object

```
 public class DepartmentSchema
{
    public int Parent { get; set; }
    public int Child { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a `List<DepartmentSchema>` with the following results:

```
Parent | Child
---------------
  4    |   1
  8    |   4
  5    |   7
  4    |   2
  8    |   4
  4    |   1
```

I want to group all the objects that has the same parent value AND child value
After the grouping what I want in result is the following list

```
 Parent | Child
---------------
  4    |   1
  8    |   4
  5    |   7
  4    |   2
```

I manage to success using IGrouping =>

`departmentSchema.GroupBy(x => new { x.Parent, x.Child }).ToList();`

but the result were`List<IGrouping<'a,DepartmentSchema>>` instead of `List<DepartmentSchema>`

I know I can make a new foreach loop and create a new `List<DepartmentSchema>` from the group list but I wonder if there is any better way

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since what you want is one element from each group, just select them out:

```
departmentSchema
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Parent, x.Child })
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

However, since what you are *really* doing is making a list of *distinct elements*, I think the sequence operator you really want is Jon's `DistinctBy`. Read about that here:

[LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Comment: Yeah, thats solving the problem. 
Thanks Eric